# Yii2 migration типы

Tags: yii2

Как создать в миграциях типы таких полей как
`uuid`, `xml`, `json`, `point`, `path`, `money`, `macaddr` и другие не стандартные типы. Так как когда я делаю `Schema::TYPE_BIGINT` то в если посмотреть, то там нету данных тип полей. А только самые распространенные. Как мне правильно создать миграцию с такими вот типами полей.

И второй вопрос. Прошуршав интернет я увидел множество вариантов создания id поля в таблице , разные варианты. С использованиям `bigserial` и еще много вариантов, так какой лучше? Каким образом в миграциях `yii2` вы создаете поле для `id`

Я использую PostgreSQL 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Schema` предусмотрены, только самые распространённые типы полей. Yii2 (как и PHP, на котором он написан) поддерживает различные СУБД и для всех них естественно константы не делают.

В подобных случаях есть 2 способа выйти из положения.

- Вместо констант класса `Schema` прописывать тип вручную, как в Yii1.

Пример:

```
$this->createTable('tbl_news', array(
   'id' => 'pk',
   'title' => 'string NOT NULL',
   'content' => 'text',
 ));
```

Константы класса `Schema` просто заменяют тип поля в строках из примера выше (см. [документацию](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-schema)).

- Создавать миграции на основе чистого SQL.

Так как Вы используете типы полей специфичные для PostgreSQL, об совместимости с другими СУБД нет смысла говорить (это тема как минимум для отдельного разговора, т.к. в данном случае обеспечение совместимости требует довольно хитрой реализации).